# populate the second select box based on the selection of first select box

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

There are two drop downs ,second drop down will be populated based on the first select box.
Both of them will be populated from the database. I have populate the first select box , also the second select box is populated, but all the values are coming as a one value. 
first select box :

```
<select id="country_obj" name="custCountry" class="field_size_e" onchange="populateSecValues(this);">
    <option value="">-select-</option>
    <% 
        Iterator contryIter = countries.iterator();
        Lookup lookup = null;
        while(contryIter.hasNext()) {
            lookup = (Lookup)contryIter.next();
            out.print("<option value='"+lookup.getValue()+"'");
            out.print(">");
            out.print(lookup.getLabel());
            out.println("</option>");
        }
    %>
</select>
```

function for on change :

```
function populateSecValues(obj) {
    alert("enter the function");
    var country = obj.value;

    $.get('/maintenance/timeZoneFinder.jsp?country='+country, function(responseData) {
            $("#zones").html(responseData);
    }); 
}

timeZoneFinder.jsp

<%
    ResultSet rset = null;
    Connection  conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    String SQL_COMMAND = "";

    try {
        conn  = ConnectionManager.getConnection();

        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String country = request.getParameter("country");

        System.out.println("country========>"+country);
        SQL_COMMAND="select a.full_name from org_base.time_zone a where a.country_code='"+country+"'";
        rset = stmt.executeQuery(SQL_COMMAND);
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rset.getMetaData();
        int col = meta.getColumnCount();
        while(rset.next()){
        out.print("<option value='"+rset.getString(1)+"' >'"+rset.getString(1)+"'</option>");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        if (rset != null) rset.close();
        if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
        if (conn != null) conn.close();
    }

%>
```

second select box html

```
<select>
<option value="" id="zones" class="field_size_e">-<%=bundle.getString("common.select") %>-</option>

</select>
```

Comment: what do you mean with `all the values are coming as a one value`? Any screenshot?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL the query that i have executed "select a.full_name from org_base.time_zone a where a.country_code='"+country+"'"
there are several values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [distinct](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) like;

```
SQL_COMMAND="select distinct(a.full_name) from org_base.time_zone a where a.country_code='"+country+"'";
```

**Edit:** Also you are putting some extra quotes on iteration part. Update it like;

```
while(rset.next()){
   out.print("<option value='' >-select time zone--</option>");
   out.print("<option value='" + rset.getString(1) + "' >" + rset.getString(1) + "</option>");
}
```

Also you can use ;

**HTML:**

```
<select id="select"></select>
<button id="click">Populate</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#click").on('click', function() {
        var html = '<option value="val1">Val-1</option><option value="val12">Val-12</option>';
        $("#select").append(html);

    });
});
```

Have a look at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7kHB/3/) for working fiddle example

Your selectbox is wrong, you need to correct it like below;

```
<select id="zones">
    <option value="" class="field_size_e">-<%=bundle.getString("common.select") %>-</option>
</select>
```

For warn user for selecting time zone;

function populateSecValues(obj) {
    var country = obj.value;

```
$.get('/maintenance/timeZoneFinder.jsp?country='+country, function(responseData) {
        $("#zones").html(responseData);
        alert("Please select time zone");
        $("#zones:first").focus();
});
```

}

Comment: you are not getting it,i want the values to displayed as different options in drop down

Comment: first drop down is for the countries for which i use another table and for second drop down i use different table

Comment: On your current implementation, you are only getting one option?

Comment: i am getting all the values but as a single string (all the values are displayed in second drop down but as a single string)

Comment: Could you please tell me the response text? There is something wrong on out.print("<option value='"+rset.getString(1)+"' >'"+rset.getString(1)+"'</option>")

Comment: yea event i have put an alert over there and all the values are coming 
 eg <option value="some vlaue" >somevalue</option>....and so on

Comment: Ok then, last thing left. You have error on your selectbox html. Could you please also put html selectbox part of your code to your question? I have added sample html simulation on my answer

Comment: i have edit it ,also i want to populate the second drop down automatically not by clicking any button.

Comment: It is just example. You need to put it ajax calbback section. Your selectbox is false. I have added correct one to  my asnwer

Comment: my mistake i put the id in the wrong place thank you so much for the help .appreciate your effort
there is an another thing which i want to do is when the user select the country time zones will be auto populated, but after selecting the country i want to make an alert "Please select the time zone" and the first entry in time zone should be "--Please select the time zone--"

Comment: this is ok but first option should be "-select time zone--"
when the user doesn't select any country this option is present in second drop down but after selecting country second drop down populates with the various option but not with the default option

Comment: But, you need to use my latest code. refer my answer. use `append` instead of `html` on js part

Comment: Or if you use `html` on js part, you can use out.print("<option value='' >-select time zone--</option>"); on java side. Check my answer